Reading from a complex xml based on attribute values with python
I am trying to parse an xml using elemtree in python.
Its structure means the difference between nodes are not in the tags but in the descriptions provided in the attributes. I'm really struggling to dig into the xml. Most of the time I return 'None'.
I tried lots of examples from elemtree tutorials but they seem to involve simpler layouts of.xml.
I thought something like this would work but it returns None.
xml.find('.//double [@name="a"]')

Where my xml looks like this (Maybe this is not the best layout of an xml, but it is what I have to work with)
<datatop number="10">
    <variable0>100325</variable0>
    <variable1>7654</variable1>
    <data id="1" desc="Node1">
        <double name="a" desc="attribute a">75</double>
        <double name="b" desc="attribute b">45</double>
        <double name="c" desc="attribute c">354</double>
    </data>
    <data id="2" desc="Node2">
        <doubleArray name="d" desc="number array d">21645 22645 23645 24645</doubleArray>
        <doubleArray name="e" desc="number array e">31645 32645 33645 34645</doubleArray>
    </data>
</datatop>

UPDATED:
This is me re-creating the minimal code to recreate the example and trouble shooting along the way.  I was on the right lines, but the space was tripping me up.  Thanks for the pointers.
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
XMLREAD = ET.parse('D:\example.xml')
XMLROOT = XMLREAD.getroot()
print(ET.tostring(XMLROOT))
print(XMLROOT.find('variable0').text)
print(ET.tostring(XMLREAD.find('.//double[@name="a"]')))
print(XMLREAD.find('.//double[@name="a"]').text)

